# shell script runs old version of itself

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

I am running AIX 7.1.0.0. My $SHELL is /usr/bin/ksh

I have a ksh script file coded in /bin/ksh which runs in a infinite while [ 1 -eq 1 ] loop in the background and it has a trap '' HUP coded to never hang up after I log off.

This script is processing a file for which it checks a directory in this infinite loop every 60 sec.

Bizarre thing is that it works correctly under current version every 2nd iteration. The content of the input file is subject to change but it is irrelevant. It should process it every time the same way. I checked there is no other process of this script running, other than the one in corrected version.

The  older version contains bugs which I fixed in vi (there is no vim on my AIX) and the script which I launched is the fixed one. I do not understand why the old, faulty version is invoked and from where does the system get it if it was overwritten by me.

Comment: A [mre] would do a lot of good. If we don't have enough information to generate the problem to see it ourselves, we can't test or trust our answers. In particular, _how_ does the script call itself?

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind is the concept of an _unlinked inode_. A file can exist even after all the directory entries pointing to it have been deleted, if something still has it opened. So if you had an old copy that had never exited and is still running, it could still be using the old file, even though that file isn't linked from the directory anymore. So how exactly the "no other process running" check was done is important (if you only checked if anything has the inode for the new version open, that wouldn't find copies of the old script if it's a separate now-unlinked inode).

Comment: (...it also wouldn't hurt to know the specific bug you're using to detect that the old version of the script is being invoked -- if it's a problem that could also be caused by a race condition, then that's a whole new possible diagnosis).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the unlinked inode might be the case. During the correction of the file, I had two putty sessions opened. In first I had the vi session of the file opened, in the second one, I killed that vi session. Then I opened again the file in vi and did the fixes. If this is the case, how can I find this unlinked inode ?
As for detection of older version - I see in the output file the script produces, that it generates old messages and basically does things which have been rewritten.
As for the calling - I launch it using an absolute path and in background /some/path/file.ksh &

Comment: I already checked the default vi's buffer directory which is /var/tmp and there is nothing there. I also used fuser -c to find any processes which would use a file with the name of the script file - nothing. Same with lsof. Could it be that only remounting the file system where script file is located, could fix this, or rebooting the lpar ?

Comment: If your local `fuser` looks for accesses _to the inode_, that doesn't mean it'll find other inodes that were formerly linked to the same filename but are no longer linked to that name now.

Comment: Anyhow -- I could tell you how to look for the unlinked inode being used _in Linux_ (where procfs still shows references to the old name but with "(deleted)" added to the link name in `/proc/###/fds`, and `lsof` and similar can get that same data), but I don't know for AIX; been years since I had an AIX box to admin. [unix.se] might be a better place for that, being more a sysadmin question than a coding one.

Comment: And yes, unmounting the filesystem or rebooting should kill any processes using unlinked inodes quite thoroughly.

Comment: btw, if you know you did the edit that didn't get saved in `vi` or any other specific editor, one thing you can do is use `stat` to look at the file's inode number, change the file, save it with that editor, and `stat` it again to see if the inode number changes. If it stays the same, you know your local copy of vi is changing the file in-place; if it doesn't, you know it's doing an atomic update by creating a new file and renaming it over the old one (which means you have a new inode at the old location, potentially leaving any handles on the old version still pointing at the unlinked copy).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on /proc/<pid>/fd and stat. on AIX it's istat. I found this very helpful in finding files/inodes opened by a given process

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-list-files-opened-process

For me it did the trick to kill all processes that were running from the file system where the script file is located. I also deleted it and recreated. I tested several iterations of the script running in the background, with input files having different content. It's working now under new version.

As for modification of inode number by vi - no, it updates the current one.